# svn2git rules regex

Tags: regex, svn2git

I'm trying to reduce my ruleset for svn2git. My tree looks like this..

```
A/foo
B/foo
C/foo
D/foo
```

I want to put A, B, and C under a legacy folder and that works. I want D to be it's own top level folder.

My current rule is..

```
match /(A|B|C)/([^/]+)/
  repository myrepo
  branch legacy/\1/\2
end match
```

Is it possible to modify the rule such that D does not end up legacy without having to define another rule?

End result should be:

```
legacy/A/foo
legacy/B/foo
legacy/C/foo
D/foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I'm not sure how **svn2git** RegEx might look like. However, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/pVZi3e/1/) might create your outputs by simply keeping <kbd>D/foo</kbd> as is, and then only changing your other three inputs using two groups plus a middle boundary <kbd>/</kbd>:

```
^(A|B|C)\/(foo)
```

[image]

You can probably change your codes based on this RegEx.

I'm not really sure, but my guess is that you codes might change to something similar to:

```
match /^(A|B|C)\/(foo)/
  repository myrepo
  branch legacy/\1/\2
end match
```

It the code would work, it would probably work without <kbd>^</kbd>:

```
match /(A|B|C)\/(foo)/
  repository myrepo
  branch legacy/\1/\2
end match
```

Comment: Interesting. I put your regex in another tester and it doesn't match on `D/foo`. I haven't run it in `svn2git` yet but I suspect it won't work because it works on matching and the branch line works on substitution.

http://www.regexe.com/

Comment: Is it possible to do substation without a pool or dictionary? I found some info here: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-conditional-replacement.html