# svn2git regex variable substition

Tags: regex, git, svn2git

Following up on this question: [svn2git rules regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855091/svn2git-rules-regex)

I'm migrating our code from SVN to git using svn2git (KDE version). Source tree looks like this:

```
A/foo
B/foo
C/foo
D/foo
```

I'm trying to write a rule that will match on all A,B,C, and D. For A,B, and C I want it to prepend legacy.

```
legacy/A/foo
legacy/B/foo
legacy/C/foo
D/foo
```

`([A|B|C]+)` almost does it with `legacy/\1`. but it doesn't match on `D`.
https://regex101.com/r/pVZi3e/4

@Emma

Comment: I'm just starting to learn how to use regex. I realize D is missing but I wasn't sure how to incorporate it without adding `legacy/D/foo` to the output. I only want `D/foo` Is there a way to do variable substitution without a pool or dictionary?

Comment: The problem is I need a 'rule' that match A,B,C,D and only prepends legacy to A,B,C. D should not be modified.

Comment: Also, aren't you getting the same behavior as you wanted? Your A,B and C folders are getting changed and D one remains same, which is what you wanted? Is it necessary for D to match? If yes, then the only option I see is to have another rule that matches D where you don't append legacy string.

Comment: I could have 2 rules but I was trying to cut down. I already have a couple hundred rules.

Comment: Well, I don't see a way with simple regex replacement for applying to two different kind of rules, so feel like you will have to add one. Seems its unavoidable given current circumstances.

Comment: Ok. That's what I feared. More rules here I come :(
 Thanks!